# Cospectral mate of rhombic dodecahedron

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

I am wondering if the following pair of cospectral graphs was previously known.

The rhombic dodecahedron graph looks like this (graph6 string: 'M?????rrAiTOd_YO?'):[image: rhombic dodecahedron]

As far as I know, it was previously unknown whether it is determined by ts spectrum. On [Wolfram Mathowrld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RhombicDodecahedralGraph.html), in the table describing properties of the graph, it simply has a "?" in the field for "determined by spectrum". However, I have found a cospectral (with respect to adjacency matrices) mate for this graph, which is displayed below (graph6 string: 'M?????rrAiTOX_eO?'
):[image: mate]

I checked in Sage and you cannot go from one to the other through Godsil-McKay switching (EDIT: I made a mistake here, you can get them from GM switching as @KrystalGuo points out below). They are also cospectral with respect to Laplacians, signless Laplacians, and normalized Laplacians. Though maybe this follows from adjacency cospectrality since they are biregular bipartite graphs? For what it is worth, both graphs are induced subgraphs of the Hoffman graph, which is the unique cospectral mate of the 4-cube. The 4-cube also contains the rhombic dodecahedron as an induced subgraph but not the cospectral mate. They are also both edge-transitive.

Comment: There are two polyhedra with 3 squares and 1 triangle at each vertex, one which has cubic symmetry and one which does not. Do you know if the second polyhedron is related to the cospectral graph?

Comment: I don't even see why are they not isomorphic...

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Well one is planar and the other isn't, but that may be hard to see. The rhombic dodecahedron has radius 4, but the cospectral mate has radius 3. Also, the cospectral mate has pairs of vertices with the same neighborhood, but the rhombic dodecahedron does not.

Comment: @DouglasZare Do you mean the pseudorhombicuboctahedron? Not that I know of. Although the line graph of the rhombic dodecahedron is related to the rhombicuboctahedron (the one with cubic symmetry you mentioned). The line graph is isomorphic with to this, except that the squares in the rhombicuboctahedron are made into K_4's.

Comment: For what it's worth, I just realized a nice description of the cospectral mate. You start with a K_4, subdivide every edge, then clone the vertices corresponding to the original vertices of the K_4, which is why you end up with vertices with the same neighborhood.

Comment: The two graphs are related by Godsil-McKay switching. The set $S = \{0,1,2,3\}$ is  a switching set. For the first graph (graph6 string: 'M?????rrAiTOd_YO?'), each degree $3$ vertex is adjacent to none of the vertices of $S$ and each of the six degree $4$ vertex is adjacent to two of the vertices of $S$. When you do the Godsil-McKay switching on the rhombic dodecahedron graph with switching set $S$, you get a graph whose graph6 string is 'M????BBNDIJOX_eO?' and is isomorphic to the second graph you have provided.

Comment: @KrystalGuo You are right, I made a mistake in an if statement in Sage.

Comment: Different construction: start with the 6 vertices of an octahedron in space. Both graphs are obtained by putting 8 "tripods" $K_{1,3}$ on those. For the first graph, each triangle gets one, for the second one, every other triangle (i.e. 4 triangles whose planes give a tetrahedron) gets 2. :-)

Comment: @Wolfgang Nice!